# Power BI : Get a list of all Power BI Apps with Users having access to it

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am looking for a method to extract all the apps in Power BI and the users having access to the application.

We can get for individual users Power BI rest Apis but I am looking for a consolidated list.

Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the following [thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/List-of-Users-with-Access-to-an-App/m-p/904010) where this is already discussed? It covers the extraction of user access but the list of applications used doesn't seem to be available via PowerBI API